# main-bower-files не срабатывает фильтр под css

Tags: javascript, gulp

Плагин "main-bower-files" не хочет срабатывать, когда я использую фильтр по `js` - все работает прекрасно.
Далее прописываю его же работу для файлов стилей `css` - срабатывать не хочет((

```js
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

gulp.task('bowerjs', function(){
    return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles({base: 'bower_components', filter: '**/*.js'}))
         .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
         .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
         .pipe(uglify())
         .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
         .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('prod/scripts'))
         .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

//отрабатывает на ура, далее использую его еще раз 


gulp.task('bowercss', function(){
    return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles({base: 'bower_components', filter: '**/*.css'}))
//       .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
//       .pipe(uncss({html: ['dev/*.html']}))
//       .pipe(concat('vendor.css'))
//       .pipe(minifyCSS())
//       .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
//       .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('prod/css'))
         .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

//не хочет, закоментил так как ничего из этого на результат не влияет.
```

Может что-то недопонимаю? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: фильтр возвращает что-нибудь? Ну то есть mainBowerFiles({base: 'bower_components', filter: '**/*.css'})?

Comment: Извиняюсь... не умею делать данную проверку...

Comment: @anxiter, вот все это полотно конфигов - это ни что иное, как обычный javascript,  который правда выполняется не в браузере а в node.js рантайме. Соответственно можно использовоать методы отладки и логирования. Тот же консоль лог там есть например: https://nodejs.org/api/console.html